# Colors missing in Terminator but not terminal

Tags: command-line, bashrc, colors, terminator

My terminator won't show the colors like in my 'regular' terminal. I have written in my `.bashrc` that user is green, folder structure is blue and git repository is red (the git repository showing I also added).

My terminator does show the git repository in the prompt, so it is reading my `.bashrc`, but it won't the different parts.

If I use the `l` command it does show green and blue `files`/`folders`. So it's not a question of being able to show colors. Does anyone recognize the problem and know how to fix it?

Here's my `.bashrc`:

```sh
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt


# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

#### Edit 1

My terminal looks like this:

[image: colors in terminal]

My terminator looks like this:

[image: colorless terminator]

I would like terminator to also show the colors like in my terminal.

In case it matters, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and terminator v0.98.

#### Edit 2

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm

$ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$
```

Comment: Could you please add more detail? What *exactly* does Terminator display and do you want it to look like? One or more screenshots, possibly with annotations, would greatly help to illustrate your issue.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `echo "$TERM"` and `echo "$PS1"` (in Terminator)? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster done

Comment: Did you try `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ ' in Terminator? I guess your `PS1="\[\e..` for `xterm` might not be working correctly...

Comment: @derHugo, your hunch was right. I basically took that comment out of the if statement and just had it stand alone and that fixed it. If you submit it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @mephistophyles If you solved your issue please add an answer below and accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: @dessert, I didn't solve it, derHugo did, I'm happy to write an answer and accept it, but I figured derHugo deserved the karma/points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @derHugo pointed out in the comments to the question, setting

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\‌​[\033[00m\]:\[\033[0‌​1;34m\]\w\[\033[01;3‌​1m\]$(parse_git_bran‌​ch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

solved the problem.